# How can I transform method into an event?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner, manateeworks

How do I make this method into an event?

BarcodeScannerRenderer.cs:

```
void IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected(MWResult result)
{
   if (result != null)
   {
       try
       {
           var scan = Element as BarcodeScannerModal;
           if (scan == null)
           return;
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       }
   }
}
```

And pass the value of result into another class, specifically in here:

**(BarcodeScanner.cs)**

```
public async Task<object[]> GetResult()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<object[]> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object[]>();
        scanPage.OnScanResult += async (result) =>
        {
            object[] scanResult = new object[2];
            SharedAppSettings.Sounds.PlayBeep();
            scanResult[0] = resultFinal.text;
            scanResult[1] = resultFinal.typeText;
            await PopupNavigation.PopAsync();

            tcs.SetResult(scanResult);
        };
        return await tcs.Task;
    }
```

If you ever wonder what type of Barcode Scanner I am using, **it's Manatee Works Barcode Scanner.**

Comment: `scanPage.OnScanResult ` isn't this already an event? And `void IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected(MWResult result)` doesn't seem to actually do anything with `result` apart from checking for null.

Comment: That's why I'm asking for a help, not a blank reason just to say "It's really wrong." Besides, if know such things, I won't mind asking anymore. Basically this should be the main goal of this site I guess for those newbies, am I right? I really don't know why people just do down-voting without even giving an answer, it's pretty that simple I guess for them since they've experienced a lot of these things, yet not an open-minded persona for being too high of themselves.

Comment: But thanks for the response @Fildor , I really appreciate it.

Comment: Ah, don't take downvotes personal. You can check against [ask] to see if you can improve your question to avoid them. In fact, I didn't write an answer, because the question is actually not that easy to answer. Giving you an example on how to make the first snippet an event is fairly easy. But your second snippet shows your design is based on polling the result. That contradicts any event-based approach. It would be good to know what `scanPage` is for examle since you seem to register an event on that already.

Comment: Also in first snippet: `Element` seems to fall out of the sky. Where does it come from?

Answer (score 1):

This answer will probably have to be adapted to changes to the question, so do not consider it complete:

To raise an event you'd do something like this:

```
// Given you have a custom EventArgs class ...
// Define an event on which clients can register their handlers
public event EventHandler<BCDetectedEventArgs> BarcodeDetected;

// infoObject should probably be of the type what `scan` is.
protected virtual void OnBarcodeDetected( object infoObject ) 
{
    // Check if there is at least one handler registered
    var handler = BarcodeDetected;
    if( handler != null )
    {

         handler(this, new BCDetectedEventArgs(infoObject));
    }
}

void IScanSuccessCallback.barcodeDetected(MWResult result)
{
   if (result != null)
   {
       try
       {
           var scan = Element as BarcodeScannerModal;
           if (scan == null)
              return;
           else
              OnBarcodeDetected( scan );
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       }
   }
}
```

See also for reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.110).aspx

The part in BarcodeScanner.cs is a little more tricky because your snippet suggests a "polling" design. You would first have to adapt to register to the event from above snippet and act on the event in an appropriate handler method.

Comment: This is what should be called as an "answer to a question". Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. you saved my time. :-)